# Node.js encoding UTF-8 issue

Tags: node.js, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have been facing an issue on node.js express framework encoding/decoding style.
Brief background, I store pdf file in mysql database with longblob data-type with latin1 charset. From server side, i need to send the binary data with UTF8 Encoding format as my client knows utf8 decoding format only.
I tried all the possible solutions available on google.

For ex: 
new Buffer(mySqlData).toString('utf8');
Already tried module "UTF8" with given functionality utf8.encode(mySqlData); But it is not working.

Also i already tried "base64" encoding and retrieve data at client with base64 decoding. It is working just fine but i need to have utf8 encoding set. Also you know base64 certainly increase the size.

Please help guys.

Comment: How do you send binary data as utf-8?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, your problem is the conversion of latin to utf-8. If you just call your `buffer.toString('utf-8')`, the latin encoded characters were wrong.

To convert other charset to utf-8, the simple wai is to use `iconv` and `icu-charset-detector`. With that, you can switch to utf-8 from all possibles charset (except certains charset).

This is an example of conversion using stream. The result stream is encoded with utf-8 :

```
var charsetDetector     = require("node-icu-charset-detector"),
    Iconv               = require('iconv').Iconv,
    Stream              = require('stream'),

function convertToUtf8(source, callback) {
    var iconv,
        charsetTestStream = new Stream.PassThrough(),
        newResStream      = new Stream.PassThrough();

    source.pipe(charsetTestStream);
    source.pipe(newResStream);

    charsetDetector.detectCharsetStream(charsetTestStream, function (charset) {
        if (!iconv && charset && !/utf-*8/i.test(charset.toString())) {
            try {
                iconv = new Iconv(charset, 'utf-8');
                console.log('Converting from charset %s to utf-8', charset);
                iconv.on('error', function (err) {
                    callback(err);
                });

                var convertStream = newResStream.pipe(iconv);
                callback(null, convertStream);
            } catch(err) {
                callback(err);
            }
            return;
        }
        callback(null, newResStream);
    });
}
```